# Нет перевода в предупреждении при попытке проголосовать за комментарий к заблокированному вопросу

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии

> [image: Comments on locked posts are not eligible for voting]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11200) (вы тоже можете предлагать свои варианты по ссылке):

> Голосование недоступно для комментариев к заблокированным сообщениям

Comment: А может лучше "Для комментариев к заблокированным сообщениям голосование недоступно"?

Comment: @Qwertiy от перестановки мест слагаемых сумма не меняется :)

Comment: А как проверять?

Comment: @Qwertiy на любом комментарии к заблокированному посту. Но может надо еще ромб снять :)

Comment: Я [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/88547/178988) только что за 2 комментария проголосовал...

Comment: @Qwertiy [снимать надо ромба](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkO80.jpg)